# Arabi/Urdu Bengali, and Gujurati unicode to send SMS using SMPP

Tags: c#

Iam using this code to send unicode sms using smpp

```
Encoding ui = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode;
Encoding u8 = Encoding.UTF8;

return u8.GetString(ui.GetBytes(s));
```

These code are working for Hindi, But for other it is not working....

For other unicode I have got box box only.

please help me, if possible provide me a sample code to send arabi/urdu/gujarati unicoded sms ....

Comment: I have removed the upper case from your question. It is considered to be SHOUTING.

Comment: Why would you expect that to work? The result of encoding a string as UTF-16 big-endian *isn't* (usually) valid UTF-8.

Comment: I have solved To some extends... but not fully
Encoding ui = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode;
Encoding u8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] byteValue = Encoding.Convert(ui, u8, ui.GetBytes(s));
return u8.GetString(byteValue);

Comment: Did anybody get par to this issue? I am stuck here. Unable to send Bengali Language in SMS